# Hexa,octal,binary to Decimal(C++)

Tags: c++, decimal

I'm trying to develop a program about conversions. This program should convert binary, octal and hex numbers into decimal. This program contains some mistakes because decimal numbers are wrong. Can anyone help me, please?
Here is the code:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int Decimal,Lenght,Pos_bit,x,base,i,n;
//Pos_bit=Exponent

char c[9];
int main()
{
    Decimale=0;
    Pos_bit=0;
    n=0;
    cout<<"Select a conversion method"<<endl; 
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "1)Binary-Decimal" << endl;
    cout << "2)Octal-Decimal" << endl;
    cout << "3)Hexa-Decimal" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    switch (x) 
    {
           case (1):
           base=2;
           break;
           case (2):
           base=8;
           break;
           case (3):
           base=16;
           }
    cout<<"How many digits has the number?"<<endl;
    cin>>Lenght;
    Pos_bit=Lenght; 
    for(i=0;i<Lenght;i++,Pos_bit--)
    {
    cout<<"Type-bit value"<<endl;
    cin>>c; 
    if(base==2){
        if(c[i]==48){
        n=0;}
    else if(c[i]==49){
        n=1;}
    Decimal=Decimal+n*(pow(2,Pos_bit));
    }
    else if(base==8){
    if ((c[i]>=48)&&(c[i]<=55)){    
    n=c[i]-48;}
    Decimal=Decimal+n*(pow(8,Pos_bit));
    }
    else if(base==16){
        if((c[i]>=48 && c[i]<=57)){
        n=c[i]-48;}
    else if((c[i]>=65)&&(c[i]<=70)){
        n=c[i]-55;}
    else if((c[i]>=97)&&(c[i]<=102)){
        n=c[i]-87;}
    Decimal=Decimal+n*pow(16,Pos_bit);
    }
    }

    cout<<"Decimal number is"<<Decimal<<endl;
    getch();
    system("cls");
    return 0;
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Elaborate on your question. What is your test input? What is your expected output? What is the actual output? And could you translate all of your code into english? Context matters. And anything but output should be in english anyway. That said, what have you tried so far to isolate the error? Used a debugger? A basic hint in any case, you should really divide your program by using functions. Makes debugging way faster.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment: you should avoid "magic" numbers such as `48` or `55`, but rather use `'0'` and `'7'` etc, which is much clearer.

Comment: This is something that you should use the debugger for. Set a breakpoint after the line `cin >> x`, single-step through the code and check at every step if the actual values of the variables meet your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem is the way you handle `Pos_bit`. You have an off by one error.

Let's say I want to convert 11 from binary. `Lungh_num` and therefore `Pos_bit` start out at 2. Your first digit calculation will be

```
Decimale=Decimale + 1 * (pow(2, 2));
```

The answer to that is 4. Your final answer will be 6. Before the loop, set

```
Pos_bit = Lungh_num - 1;
```

Actually, the best thing is to forget about the `pow()` stuff altogether. Instead of

```
 Decimale=Decimale+n*pow(16,Pos_bit);
```

write

```
 Decimale = Decimale * base + n;
```

Answer (score 0):

If we don't care about input sanitization and magic numbers and other coding standard issues, you main errors were:

- We count the bit numbers from 0 to n-1, so this line should be: `Pos_bit = Lungh_num - 1;`
- In any place where you are using `c[i]` you should replace it by `c[0]`. You care only about the first character from the input, if I'm not mistaken.

Your corrected code should look like this:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int Decimale, Lungh_num, Pos_bit, x, base, i, n;
//lungh_num=n lenght;
//Pos_bit=Exponent

char c[9];
int main()
{
    Decimale = 0;
    Pos_bit = 0;
    n = 0;
    cout << "Scegli un metodo di conversione" << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "1)Binario-Decimale" << endl;
    cout << "2)Ottale-Decimale" << endl;
    cout << "3)Esadecimale-Decimale" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    switch (x)
    {
    case (1):
        base = 2;
        break;
    case (2):
        base = 8;
        break;
    case (3):
        base = 16;
    }
    cout << "Quante cifre ha il numero?" << endl;
    cin >> Lungh_num;
    Pos_bit = Lungh_num - 1;
    for (i = 0; i < Lungh_num; i++, Pos_bit--)
    {
        cout << "Digita valore bit" << endl;
        cin >> c;
        if (base == 2) {
            if (c[0] == 48) {
            n = 0;
        }
        else if (c[0] == 49) {
            n = 1;
        }
        Decimale = Decimale + n*(pow(2, Pos_bit));
        }
        else if (base == 8) {
            if ((c[0] >= 48) && (c[0] <= 55)) {
                n = c[0] - 48;
            }
            Decimale = Decimale + n*(pow(8, Pos_bit));
        }
        else if (base == 16) {
            if ((c[0] >= 48 && c[0] <= 57)) {
                n = c[0] - 48;
            }
            else if ((c[0] >= 65) && (c[0] <= 70)) {
                n = c[0] - 55;
            }
            else if ((c[0] >= 97) && (c[0] <= 102)) {
                n = c[0] - 87;
            }
            Decimale = Decimale + n*pow(16, Pos_bit);
        }
    }

    cout << "Il numero decimale e'" << Decimale << endl;
    getch();
    system("cls");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great!!Thanks Man!